# J4 default page from CiviCRM extension not working

Tags: extensions, menu-item, routing

It seems that it is not possible to set a menu item from the CiviCRM extension for Joomla as the default page in J4. Or rather when the website is visited there is no content, while the menu item is rendered as "active" and clicking the menu explicitly produces the correct content.

This worked in J3.

I'm looking for clues on why this might be so, for example

- Are there any breaking changes in how the routing for menu items provided by extensions work between J3 and J4?

Some background information on how default page "routing" would also be helpful.

Comment: Have you contacted the developer about this CiviCRM issue and about your routing question?

Comment: It is an open source/community driven extension. I have reported it but am looking for more information to support fixing or even doing it myself.